# Android Studio Fails to import Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

```
Failed to import Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':Form'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':Form'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Form:classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+.
Required by:
    FormProject:Form:unspecified
Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build#gradle;0.5.+.
Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'.
Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/'.
repo1.maven.org
```

Comment: Paste in you complete `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Even I get this while starting a new Project. I avoid starting any project in Android Studio. I rather import or open a project.

Comment: Do you have build tools installed? Check Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 6):

I sorted the problem out. It just needs a reliable internet connection to download gradle.
Thanks

Comment: This didn't work first, but I held down the Enter button (trying to force the window) and suddenly it worked.